# Python function parameter: tuple/list

Tags: python, list, coding-style, tuples

My function expects a list or a tuple as a parameter. It doesn't really care which it is, all it does is pass it to another function that accepts either a list or tuple:

```
def func(arg): # arg is tuple or list
  another_func(x)
  # do other stuff here
```

Now I need to modify the function slightly, to process an additional element:

```
def func(arg): #arg is tuple or list
  another_func(x + ['a'])
  # etc
```

Unfortunately this is not going to work: if arg is tuple, I must say `x + ('a',)`.

Obviously, I can make it work by coercing arg to list. But it isn't neat.

Is there a better way of doing that? I can't force callers to always pass a tuple, of course, since it simply shifts to work to them.

Comment: If the other function accepts either than I would send it a tuple as it will be faster for you to work with. Then what's not neat about `tuple(x) + ('a',)`?

Comment: Are tuples faster in the implementation?

Comment: constructing a tuple from string and numeric literals is faster than constructing a list. More importantly, `tuple(x)` just returns `x` if it's already a tuple whereas `list(x)` copies `x` even if it's already a list. So by using a tuple, you cut most of the work out for half of your input cases.

Comment: +1: good point about tuple vs list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `another_func` just wants a iterable you can pass `itertools.chain(x,'a')` to it.

Comment: @max  No copy is made, so it is very fast.  It's probably the most efficient Python solution.

Answer (score 4):

What about changing the other function to accept a list of params instead ?

```
def func(arg): # arg is tuple or list
  another_func('a', *x)
```

Comment: What about when another_func needs several list arguments that are affected by the same issue, or if it already has an (unrelated) *x parameter?

Comment: @max: The answer's the same.  Fix the other function.

Comment: something must be changed in the function's interface

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm hontestly confused now. If `another_func` takes two lists, why is it a bad design? Say, one list is "list or tuple of columns to print", and another is "list or tuple of rows to exclude from print". How and why should I change its interface?

Comment: @max: A tuple with an indefinite number of elements is a design error.  Tuples are usually used for a definite number of elements; the number of elements is usually fixed by the problem domain (x,y) coordinates, (r,g,b) colors, etc.  A "variable-sized" tuple is simply inappropriate.  It should be a list.  Fix the function to work with a list.  Fix the functions.  "variable length" or "indefinite length" tuples are an error.  Don't support them.  Fix them.

Comment: @S.Lott: +1 for helpful feedback, thank you. I'm curious about this though, so I've asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210981/python-variable-length-tuples.

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
l = ['a']
l.extend(x)
```

Edit:
Re-reading question, I think this is more what you want (the use of `arg` and `x` was a little confusing):

```
tuple(arg) + ('a',)
```

As others have said, this is probably not the most efficient way, but it is very clear. If your tuples/lists are small, I might use this over less clear solutions as the performance hit will be negligible. If your lists are large, use the more efficient solutions.

Comment: `extend` returns `None`, as it mutates the list.

Comment: @max I originally had "['a'].extend(x)" which is a largely useless statement, because extend returns None, as delnan pointed out

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(*args):
    print args

def a(*args):
    k = list(args)
    k.append('a')
    f(*k)

a(1, 2, 3)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 'a')
```

Comment: hmm `f(*(tuple(args)+('a',))` is better

Answer (score 2):

If an iterable is enough you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), but be aware that if function `A` (the first one called), also iterates over the iterable after calling `B`, then you might have problems since iterables cannot be rewinded. In this case you should opt for a sequence or use [`iterable.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to make a copy of the iterable:

```
import itertools as it

def A(iterable):
    iterable, backup = it.tee(iterable)
    res = B(it.chain(iterable, 'a'))
    #do something with res
    for elem in backup:
        #do something with elem

def B(iterable):
   for elem in iterable:
       #do something with elem
```

Even though `itertools.tee` isn't really that efficient if `B` consumes *all* or *most* of the iterable, at that point it's simpler to just convert `iterable` to a `tuple` or a `list`.

Comment: +1 for the clarification about rewinding of iterators. In my case, iterable is enough; I guess for the sequence case I'll just coerce to tuple as suggested by @aaronasterling

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
def foo(t):
    bar(list(t) + [other])
```

This is not very efficient though, you'd be better off passing around mutable things if you're going to be, well, mutating them.

Comment: Could you clarify please? Why is this not efficient?

Comment: @max  It's not as efficient because it copies an entire list just to add a single item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type of the iterable passed to the first function to construct what you pass to the second:

```
from itertools import chain

def func(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    another_func(type(iterable)(chain(it, ('a',))))

def another_func(arg):
    print arg

func((1,2))
# (1, 2, 'a')
func([1,2])
# [1, 2, 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your function accept any iterable.  Then use `itertools.chain` to add whatever sequence you want to the iterable.

```
from itertools import chain

def func(iterable):
    another_func(chain(iterable, ('a',)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Santiago Lezica's answer of doing

```
def foo(t):
    bar(list(t) + [other])
```

is the best because it is the simplest. (no need to import itertools stuff and use much less readable chain calls). But only use it if you expect t to be small. If t can be large you should use one of the other solutions.