# Typing Tuple when using as default argument

Tags: python, function, tuples, default, typing

I have a case where I would like users of our package to be able to select from a list of options, for example

```
run_package(some_settings=("setting_1", "session_2", "setting_3"))
```

I have used a Tuple as the default argument on this function

```
def run_package(some_settings=("setting_1",):
    ...
```

To avoid the issue with having a mutable list as default argument. I prefer this form to the alternative:

```
def run_package(some_setting=None):

    if some_setting is None:
          # set default
          some_setting = ["setting_1"]
```

as it is more explicit.

However, now I want to type this argument, e.g.

```
def run_package(some-settings: Tuple[Union[Literal["setting_1"], Literal["setting_2"], Literal["setting_3"]] = ("setting_1",)):
    ...
```

I am running into problems because, if I understand correctly, `Tuple` type must be of fixed length as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210981/python-variable-length-tuples).

This makes sense as `Tuple` is immutable. I guess this precludes its use as a default argument for a function as I have done? Are there any workarounds except for using `None` as default?

Many Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to annotate function that takes a tuple of variable length? (variadic tuple type annotation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747253/how-to-annotate-function-that-takes-a-tuple-of-variable-length-variadic-tuple)

Comment: tl;dr: `some_settings: tuple[Literal["setting_1"] | Literal["setting_2"] | Literal["setting_3"], ...]`